# JSON Syntax Error only when parsing in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, json, browser, syntax-error

I'd like to preface by saying I'm pretty new to JS, though I've been using JSONs for awhile with other programming languages.

I've been trying to get a pass some data in a JSON to a JS script, and then getting that into an HTML file. My issue right now is coming from the browser. Originally I was going to just load the JSON locally, but I learned I'd have to get it from a web request as to my knowledge, browsers don't support locally loading. I put my JSON on GitHub and referenced the raw via url. However, when I go to debug, of all things I get a Syntax error, which *does* show in Chrome's debugging terminal.

> Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' at (program) ("directory"\flashcards.json:2:14)

[image of error in chrome's terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUIUO.png)

What's weird is that I'm getting no errors in VSCode, and I've written a JSON enough times to know that it's not improper syntax.

```
{
    "flashcards":
    [
        {
            "context": "Derivatives",
            "front": "f´(sinx)",
            "back": "cosx"
        },
        {
            "context": "Derivatives",
            "front": "f´(cosx)",
            "back": "-sinx"
        }
    ]
}
```

The code that loads this JSON looks like this.

```
function loadFlashcards() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Spebby/Calculus-Revision/main/flashcards.json', true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.flashcards.length; i++) {
                var card = jsonData.flashcards[i];
                var flashcard = new Flashcard(card.context, card.front, card.back);
                console.log("Flashcard created: " + card.context, card.front, card.back);
                cards.push(flashcard);
            }
        } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
            console.log("Error loading flashcards");
        }
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
        // There was a connection error of some sort
        console.log("Error loading flashcards");
    };
    request.send();
}
```

If anyone knows what's causing this issue, please let me know. I'm also more than happy to refactor loadFlashcards() if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What you've posted is valid JSON - Chrome is probably busted, have you tried a browser that isn't busted?

Comment: While I would love nothing more than to not use chrome, I'm making this site for a friend who insists on using chrome, so unfortunately not an option.
EDIT: Just tested in Firefox, problem still exists.

Comment: your code works fine anyway - https://jsfiddle.net/ph1w2jnd/ - the error `("directory"\flashcards.json:2:14)` suggests you're loading the JSON in a script tag to be honest - just tried it, and that seems to be exactly what you are doing

Comment: perhaps you should check WHAT is actually causing the error rather than assuming it's the XMLHttpRequest (specifically, the `JSON.parse` in the onload callback) - because it's not the XMLHttpRequest that is causing the error

Comment: You could try changing `var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);` to `var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText.replaceAll('\n', ''));`. I think it's choking on the fact that the `[` is not on the same line as `"flashcards":`.

Comment: ok this is some kind of sick joke because all of a sudden I'm getting prints from the console when I previously wasn't without changing anything. 

Thanks for the suggestion Rocky, will try. And the bracket not being on the same line isn't the issue, I've tested that previously.

Comment: @RockySims - you'd think so, except JSON.parse doesn't give a fig about `\n`

Comment: `all of a sudden I'm getting prints from the console when I previously wasn't without changing anything` - that's unpossible - you probably were loading the json in a script tag, and removed that - so now it works

Comment: @JaromandaX "suggests you're loading the JSON in a script tag to be honest"  removed the script tag and that error is gone, thank you for spotting that. Thank you so much!

In terms of the impossible console prints. I was getting it before I removed the script tag, thinking about it, it's probably because I swapped to testing with Firefox instead of Chrome and somehow missed the console print outs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaromanda X Pointed out that the error I was getting suggested the error was actually coming from the HTML side. They suggested that the error was due to loading the JSON in a script tag. I forgot I had even done this, but after checking it was there and removing it, the error vanished. Thank you again Jaromanda!